# TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not float

Tags: string, python-3.x, loops

I have this code using fake date (below) and it works fine:

```
exg = ["I love apple.", 
        "there are lots of health benefits of apple.", 
        "apple is especially hight in Vitamin C,", 
        "alos provide Vitamin A as a powerful antioxidant!"]


fruit_list = ["pear", "banana", "mongo", "blueberry", "kiwi", "apple", "orange"]

for j in range(0, len(exg)):
    sentence = exg[j]
    if any(word in sentence for word in fruit_list):
        print(sentence)
```

output as following: only showing sentences contained words in the fruit_list.

```
I love apple.
there are lots of health benefits of apple.
apple is especially hight in Vitamin C,
```

Then I changed fruit_list to my real data (real_list), the real data comes from a column in an excel sheet. the reading data code as following:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/my/Desktop/my_list.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
real_list = data['name'].tolist()
```

But my code doesn't work anymore, and the error is shown below:

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-5a886e386099> in <module>()
      7 for j in range(0, len(exg)):
      8     sentence = exg[j]
----> 9     if any(word in sentence for word in real_list):
     10         print(sentence)

<ipython-input-101-5a886e386099> in <genexpr>(.0)
      7 for j in range(0, len(exg)):
      8     sentence = exg[j]
----> 9     if any(word in sentence for word in real_list):
     10         print(sentence)

TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not float
```

I'm sure the problem is from the real_list. And I can't show the real_list here (hope you understand), but has anyone experience this error message before? and any idea what could be causes of it? Please send help. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I'm sure it is too. But I would like to see it. It isn't easy to diagnose a problem when the means to reproduce it isn't even given.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. sorry i can't show you the real_list. If helps, real_list is a list of product names, so there could be punctuations (such as &,  - , (, ), space, etc.). and the list contains 700+ elements. does it helps?

Comment: and i tried to make fruit_list = ["pear", "banana", "mongo", "blueberry", "kiwi", "apple", "orange"] into an excel sheet, and it worked fine.

Comment: @S.J can you confirm that your `real_list` contains strings only and not any decimal numbers(floats)?

Comment: @S.J You should binary search your list to narrow down which items may be causing grief, then obscure the contents into a non-private string that you can share with us if you wish to get any help on the issue.

Comment: Yes, probably they are not strings, maybe some of those values are converted to None, or numbers, you could try converting word to string in the any call
`if any(str(word) in sentence for word in fruit_list):`

Comment: Thank you so much for all your comments!! Special thanks to tkhurana96 and Santiago. It turned out that there is a "N/A" in my real_list, which is float.... stupid error. Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 0):

FIXED:

There was a "N/A" in the real_list, which is a float.

Thanks for all your comments!!